# How to get edge slided vertex to become parallel to another point?

Tags: geometry

How do I get the sliding vertex to snap to perfectly snap to the adjacent line's y-height, as described in the gif below?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you just want to connect that two lines as you showed in the gif, do it like this:

1. enable automerge and split edges in "Tools"
2. extrude the vertex with G X to the left -> watch that magic vertex appearing at the intersection
3. delete the other two vertices

[image]